# Is there an event called after a gridview is completely finished?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Or a way to detect it is finsihed rendering?

Actually almost exactly this question

[Gridview, is there an event, how would I determine that it has finished being rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037206/gridview-is-there-an-event-how-would-i-determine-that-it-has-finished-being-re)

but he does not state exactly how he detected that everything had been drawn/resized.

EDIT: (Adding my comment from below to specify what i am trying to do)

I am trying to create a work around for static header for a gridview by basically dynamically adding another gridview above the one that actually has the data in it. I resorted to this after trying about 12 different suggestions/solutions with no real luck. What i have works pretty well except that the new header is rendered before the one with the data in it completes its re-sizing, I realize what i am trying might not even work since it might require another postback to re-render the new one after i find the sizes of the column headers but thought i might get around that with an update panel.

I realize this might not be the most elegant solution but honestly have yet to find any solutions to this problem that come even close to elegant or have even worked correctly with  current browsers.

Comment: the poster on that question states: *I managed to solve the problem by registering a function with the page load which is called after the controls have been drawn*

Comment: Right how did he detect that the controls have been drawn?

Comment: *by registering a function with the page load* which means either by using `client.registerscriptblock` or by using pure client-side javascript / jquery.

Answer (score 2):

It renders at the client so the server doesn't know what is happening there.

You are probably looking for the `DataBound` event.

Otherwise, at the client, you can determine when the page has finished loading (the jquery ready function) and then call back to the server.  But I can't imagine anything useful you could do.  If you send more data to the client and it renders again, you could have an infinite loop.

Comment: DataBound is called before everything is drawn and re-sized though. so basically too early. I am trying to detect the width of some columns that are auto-sizing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in an ASP.Net webpage is rendered at the same consecutively at the same stage of the lifecycle (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), so the Gridview will be rendered between `Gridview_PreRenderComplete` and `Gridview_Unload`.

You page `PreRender` will fire, then the control `PreRender`, then the page will call the Gridview Render method (there is no event for this) then the control `Unload` will fire and then the page `Unload` will fire.

Other posters to this question are referring to the client side rendering whereas I am referring to the server side rendering process. Which is it that you are actually after and why please?

Comment: Trying to detect the width of columns that are dynamically generated by the data source and are re-sizing as the table loads. They are nice and static once it is finished loading.

Comment: Dimensions are not available from the server side unless you set them explicitly with a CSS style or similar. This means that if you want to work out what size they will be you will need to detect this on the client with Javascript.

Comment: I am trying to create a work around for static header for a gridview by basically dynamically adding another gridview above the one that actually has the data in it. I resorted to this after trying about 12 different suggestions/solutions with no real luck. What i have works pretty well except that the new header is rendered before the one with the data in it completes its resizing, I realize what i am trying might not even work since it might require another postback to rerender the new one after i find the sizes of the column headers but thought i might get around that with an update panel.

Comment: Okay, there are a few ways of doing what you want, but first I would like to know why? That may help me work out what approach is best. Why is the solution offered by Asp.Net Gridview not okay for what you want?